# What image types are supported with gtkmm's Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_file()?

Tags: image, gtkmm

What image types are supported with gtkmm's Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_file()? Is it system-dependant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vector<Gdk::PixbufFormat> list = Gdk::Pixbuf::get_formats();
vector<Gdk::PixbufFormat>::const_iterator it;

for (it = list.begin(); it!=list.end(); it++)
{
    cout << it->get_name();
    cout << " - ";
    cout<< it->get_description();
    cout << endl;
}
```

That one above lists all formats available for Pixbufs.